# iterate through map that contains list of maps with eachFor

Tags: flutter, data-structures, dart

I need to fetch data from API
when I get the data I need to iterate through them

the problem is this API is structured like this :

```
{
  "events": [
    {
      "image_url": "sun.jpg", 
      "name_ar": "sun",
      "name_en": "sun"
    }, 
    {
      "image_url": "sun.jpg", 
      "name_ar": "sun",
      "name_en": "sun"
    }, 
    ......
  ]
}
```

list of maps inside a map

this is my code 
forEach only gives me a key and a value 
the key isn't useful for me ..I am left with only the value
I need some sort of index

```dart
class Events with ChangeNotifier{
List<Event> _eventsList = [];
List<Event> get eventsList {
    return [..._eventsList];
  }
Future<void> fetchEvents(http.Client client) async {
    try {
      //fetch api
      final response =  await client.get(globals.apiUrl + '/events/');
      // json.decode
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      final List<Event> loadedEvents = [];
      //store events into a List<Event>
      extractedData.forEach((key,eventData) {
        print(key);//evnts
        print(eventData);//this gives the list of maps
        loadedEvents.add(Event(
          name_en: eventData[0]['name_en'],
          name_ar: eventData[0]['name_ar'],
          image_url: eventData[0]['image_url'],
        ));
      });
      _eventsList = loadedEvents;
      //for the provider
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      throw (error);
    }
  }
}


//Event class 
class Event with ChangeNotifier {
  final String image_url;
  final String name_ar;
  final String name_en;

  Event({this.image_url, this.name_ar, this.name_en});
}
```

of course,​ this results in only the first event item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to iterate the loop just use https://app.quicktype.io/ to generate the model class for your response and use like below

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final eventsResponse = eventsResponseFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

EventsResponse eventsResponseFromJson(String str) => EventsResponse.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String eventsResponseToJson(EventsResponse data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class EventsResponse {
    List<Event> events;

    EventsResponse({
        this.events,
    });

    factory EventsResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => EventsResponse(
    events: json["events"] == null ? null : List<Event>.from(json["events"].map((x) => Event.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "events": events == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(events.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Event {
    String imageUrl;
    String nameAr;
    String nameEn;

    Event({
        this.imageUrl,
        this.nameAr,
        this.nameEn,
    });

    factory Event.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Event(
        imageUrl: json["image_url"] == null ? null : json["image_url"],
        nameAr: json["name_ar"] == null ? null : json["name_ar"],
        nameEn: json["name_en"] == null ? null : json["name_en"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "image_url": imageUrl == null ? null : imageUrl,
        "name_ar": nameAr == null ? null : nameAr,
        "name_en": nameEn == null ? null : nameEn,
    };
}
```

and replace you API call with below

```
Future<void> fetchEvents(http.Client client) async {
    try {
      //fetch api
      final response =  await client.get(globals.apiUrl + '/events/');
      final List<Event> loadedEvents = new List();
      //store events into a List<Event>
      EventsResponse eventResponse = eventsResponseFromJson(response.body);
      loadedEvents.addAll(eventResponse.events);
      //for the provider
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      throw (error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pull out the `'events'` value from the map explicitly and then iterate over the events in that list. You'll need to cast with `as List` to see it as a `List<dynamic>` and then call `.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>()` to see it as a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`;

```
final extractedData = jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
final encodedEvents = (extractedData['events'] as List).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
final loadedEvents = [
  for(final event in encodedEvents)
    Event(
      name_en: event['name_en'],
      name_ar: event['name_ar'],
      image_url: eventData[0]['image_url'],
    ),
];
```